# how to use Sql query to search text in CSV file and avoid iteration

Tags: c#, algorithms, csv

I have one A File and many input files ,All files have CSV format . I want to match text of one column of all input files with one of the column of A file .
I have stored all column value of File A in HashSet for fast search.

```
1- Now iterate All input files uses First loop
2-       {iterate all elements in each file uses second loop 
3-           {
              and iterate all lines in hashset uses Third loop .
                {
                    Store All lines in List and append true in the end at the end of line if Match found
                 }
                    Delete The input File


              //Removed Lines
4-            //      iterate through all stored lines
             //    {
            //      Write in same file
            //     }

             //Added Lined 
                File.WriteAllLine(...)

             }
         }
```

1-When i find the match ,i have to make change input File , For this purpose i have to use FileWriteStream, a Collection to store lines and another loop. Delete the File and write again. Is there any optimal solution to achieve this

2- I have used linear Search in order to Search the text in A file .Is it 'okay' to use Dictionary so that i takes O(1) to get the element.

3- Is there any good optimal way to read all this .using Oledb 'can i use the query'?

Comment: 1) If the file is small enough to fit into memory, please consider using [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 2) I'm not sure why you're iterating over the HashSet; I think you should be using the HashSet to perform fast lookups - not iterating over each line.

Comment: @JTrana I am iterating over collection because i have to match a part in row rather than whole row .

Comment: I believe this question was answered in another thread:
[How to use SQL against a CSV file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624286/how-to-use-sql-against-a-csv-file